# Load roles from database based in JWT's userId

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to implement some database fetching in my JWT authentication, so that I can dinamically fetch the roles and other info from the database, I would ideally only want to store the userId in the JWT payload.

Doing that, I can do stuff like store the date where the password was last changed, and refuse the token in case it was issued before that.

The problem is that I have no idea where on the chain I would do such thing, I'm just getting started with .NET/ASP.NET

I have this on my `ConfigureServices` currently:

```cs
var jwtKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Secret"]);
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(jwtKey),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
        };
    });
```

And this on my `Configure`:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

With that, I can access some user info inside a controller's action with `User.Identity.Name` for example, how would I do that after loading the model from the DB?

Comment: Token validation (making sure the token hasn't expired or if it's signed by the correct issuer), should be done by middleware BEFORE the end point is hit, and therefore, everything that you want to do should be in the token itself.

Comment: If you use a dbcontext derived from IdentityDbContext you get all the tables related to users, roles etc and you can use the identity api for registering and authentcation

Comment: are you generating the token in your api. if yes, then you can add roles, userid or whatever information during token creation as claims.

Answer (score 0):

**REQUIREMENTS**

These are usually the main things you will care about:

- APIs must have access to domain specific claims so that they can authorize correctly
- Tokens returned to internet clients are kept confidential

**OPTION 1**

The optimal way to meet the requirements is to issue opaque tokens to internet clients, then introspect them before they reach the API, as described in the [Phantom Token Approach](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/).

An Authorization Server can then reach out to your domain specific data at the time of token issuance, to include custom claims in access tokens.

**OPTION 2**

In the API code there are two stages involved in integrating custom claims, and the second of these can be customized:

- Verify the JWT access token
- Form a ClaimsPrincipal

If your Authorization Server doesn't support opaque access tokens, another option that will work is a Custom Authentication Handler. It adds some complexity to your API though. See [this blog post of mine](https://authguidance.com/net-core-api-oauth-integration/) and [this code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/security/CustomAuthenticationHandler.cs).